# Single Decision Tree output from a XGBoost Model

Tags: boosting

Would it be methodologically acceptable to export all the different decision trees constructed by an XGBoost model and test them singularly as a potential risk classification system?

Comment: 0. Welcome to CV.SE. 1. Unusual question (+1). Unfortunately though it is not an obviously viable proposal.

Answer (score 2):

For an XGBoost model, examining one tree at a time makes little sense, because gradient boosting is an iterative algorithm primarily driven by the "mistakes" done up to that point. Thus the $i$-th tree on it's own has little practical meaning. For all we know, a seemingly "risky" tree corrects existing biases/lapses of the overall XGBoost model.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Which method would you use then to derive a simple classification system (clinical medicine context so it has to be really easy but with good accuracy) from a reasonably good XGBoost Model (accuracy 0.87%)?

Comment: I am glad I could help. I think your follow-up question is better as a separate question. That said, if there was a "*really easy but with good accuracy*" algorithm already in place, we wouldn't have to use XGBoost to begin with. Maybe [GAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_additive_model)s are viable alternative for what you want but this can be case-specific. Do check them though, they can be interpretable and quite competitive.

Comment: @fb95 Frank Harrell’s book is built around answering the question of how to build and utilize complex nonlinear models in a medical setting.

Comment: @Sycorax: We can say "Regression Modeling Strategies"(+1), it's not a dirty word. :D (Well, the spelling is a bit off but you know...  c'est la vie.)